# How is Conway numbering the hyperbolic groups in his Table 18.1?

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-groups

Conway lists many hyperbolic groups in his Table 18.1 on pages 239-240 of *The Symmetries of Things*.  Here are scans of those pages:
[image]
and
[image]
The groups are sorted in decreasing order of their characteristic, from $0$ down to $-1/8$.  I understand the orbifold-based names of the groups and I know how to compute their characteristics.  But I don't understand how Conway is numbering them.  His numbers, in the leftmost column, jump up in steps that don't seem to correspond to anything --- including a step of 39, in going from $\omega+63$ to $\omega+102$.  How is Conway computing those numbers?

Comment: Please make your questions self-contained.  Not everyone has a copy of that book.

Comment: Is it not ascending order? The omitted ones maybe do not satisfy the condition of characteristic at least $-1/8$.

Answer (score 1):

I finally realized:  Conway is numbering the characteristics in numeric order; but Table 18.1, while it does list "all possibilities" in a sense, omits some lines without including ellipses to warn of those omissions.  For example, there are three omitted lines between $\omega+4$ and $\omega+8$, where those lines, numbered $\omega+5$ through $\omega+7$, are for the groups $\ast 2\; 3\; 9$, $\ast 2\; 3\; 10$, and $\ast 2\; 3\; 11$, with second-column entries $36$, $30$, and $26\;\,2/5$.

A few lines down, the line numbered just "$\omega+\hbox{}$" should be numbered $\omega+13$, where the omitted lines $\omega+12$ and $\omega+14$ are for the groups $\ast 2\;3\;16$ and $\ast 2\;3\;17$, with second-column entries $19\;\,1/5$ and $18\;\,6/11$.

Comment: If so, maybe it makes sense to let the author who maintains the errata know. https://www.mit.edu/~hlb/Symmetries_of_Things/SoTerrors.html

Comment: Thanks for telling me that Heidi Burgiel is maintaining an errata list.  I am sending her an email about Table 18.1 (and some other things).